# PHP: how to access value in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm downloading some json using the following:

```
$api_resp = json_decode(@file_get_contents($api_url),true);
```

Which give the following array (using var_dump):

```
array(4) {
  ["body"]=>
  array(1) {
    [1657134820]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      float(1.313)
    }
  }
  ["status"]=>
  string(2) "ok"
  ["time_exec"]=>
  float(0.031042098999023)
  ["time_server"]=>
  int(1657140220)
}
```

How can I access the 1.313 float value?

I'm able to access the body using $api_resp['body'], but how do I go from there?
$api_resp['body'][0] gives "PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0"

Comment: `$api_resp['body'][1657134820][0]`

Comment: The body property has an array using the key `1657134820`.  Probably that key is some id and is never the same number. 

If the body array always has 1 property, you can use php's [reset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) function.

In your case: 

`$body = reset($api_resp["body"]);`

Comment: Or just loop over `$api_resp['body']`

Comment: Thanks @Leroy, that solved it. Using reset($api_resp["body"])[0] gives me the value.